# How does one find $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{3}{(s-1)^2} \right\}$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to solve

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{3}{(s-1)^2} \right\}$$

However, it seems worse than easy. We can write this out as

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{3}{(s-1)}\frac{1}{(s-1)} \right\}, $$ where the factor $\dfrac{1}{s-1}$ recurs, so the answer must have the inverse of this in it, so we can write $$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{3}{(s-1)}\frac{1}{(s-1)} \right\} = e^t \, f(t).$$

We can then consider the damping rule which says that $\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{F(s+b) \right\} =e^{-bt} \, f(t).$

Then, with $b=-1$, we obtain:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{3}{(s-1)}\frac{1}{(s-1)} \right\}=F(s-1).$$

But the question now is, what is $F(s)$?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If $L\{f(t)\}=F(s)$, then we have $L\{tf(t)\}=-F'(s)$ [(this link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289303/proof-laplace-trasform-of-xfx); and note that:

$$\frac {3}{(s-1)^2}=-\left(\frac {3}{s-1}\right)'.$$

Moreover we have $L\{3 \, e^t\}=\frac {3}{s-1}$; therefore:

$$L^{-1} \left\{ \frac{3}{(s-1)^2} \right\}=3 \, t \, e^t.$$